# Android Studio 3.0.0-beta1 -- NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

Since upgrading Android Studio to v3.0.0-beta1 and amending classpath to `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta1'` I am being hit with the following error each time my rxjava/retrofit code throws an error (a 401 HttpException in this example).

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fatal Exception thrown on Scheduler.Worker thread.
    at rx.android.schedulers.LooperScheduler$ScheduledAction.run(LooperScheduler.java:114)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
    Caused by: rx.exceptions.OnErrorFailedException: Error occurred when trying to propagate error to Observer.onError
    at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber._onError(SafeSubscriber.java:187)
    at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onError(SafeSubscriber.java:115)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.checkTerminated(OperatorObserveOn.java:273)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:216)
    at rx.android.schedulers.LooperScheduler$ScheduledAction.run(LooperScheduler.java:107)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
    Caused by: rx.exceptions.CompositeException: 2 exceptions occurred. 
    at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber._onError(SafeSubscriber.java:187) 
    at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onError(SafeSubscriber.java:115) 
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.checkTerminated(OperatorObserveOn.java:273) 
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:216) 
    at rx.android.schedulers.LooperScheduler$ScheduledAction.run(LooperScheduler.java:107) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
    Caused by: rx.exceptions.CompositeException$CompositeExceptionCausalChain: Chain of Causes for CompositeException In Order Received =>
    at android.util.Log.getStackTraceString(Log.java:522)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.Clog_e(RuntimeInit.java:61)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.-wrap0(RuntimeInit.java)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:86)
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
    at rx.android.schedulers.LooperScheduler$ScheduledAction.run(LooperScheduler.java:118)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
    Caused by: retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.HttpException: HTTP 401 Unauthorized
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.OperatorMapResponseToBodyOrError$1.onNext(OperatorMapResponseToBodyOrError.java:43)
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.OperatorMapResponseToBodyOrError$1.onNext(OperatorMapResponseToBodyOrError.java:38)
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$RequestArbiter.request(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:173)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber$1.request(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:109)
    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:211)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.setProducer(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:105)
    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:205)
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:152)
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:138)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10346)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:100)
    at rx.internal.schedulers.CachedThreadScheduler$EventLoopWorker$1.call(CachedThreadScheduler.java:230)
    at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:269)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/devtools/build/android/desugar/runtime/ThrowableExtension;
```

- All error handlers have been set appropriately for RxJava calls.
- Android sdk build tools v26.0.1
- Tried clean, rebuild etc
- Tried disabling Instant-Run

Comment: @cricket_007 the 401 is being handled in RxJava onError handler. I believe the issue is around `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/devtools/build/android/desugar/runtime/ThrowableExtension;` as the only change in code base is updating to AS 3.0.0-beta1

Comment: There is another error in beta 1 I find that is https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64591419

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was addressed by Google and fixed in [Beta 2 update](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/08/android-studio-30-beta-2.html).

> Friday, August 11, 2017
>
> Android Studio 3.0 Beta 2 is now available in
> the Canary and Dev channels. This release fixes an issue which
> resulted in the compiler throwing a ClassNotFoundException when you
> enable Java 8 language features and specify minSdkVersion 19 or
> higher—this also caused some code analysis tools, such as ProGuard, to
> fail. For more information, see issue #64527520.

Comment: Seems like it is back with Android Studio 3.0 Beta 3

Comment: I'm seeing it in Beta 3 too. Ugh.  Any known workarounds?